# How to use dlxsudoku package in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sudoku

I'm trying to implement a sudoku solver in python using dlxsudoku package available from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlxsudoku

While trying to implement the documented code, available on the site provided i.e.

```
from dlxsudoku import Sudoku

sudoku_string_1 = "030467050920010006067300148301006027400850600090200400005624001203000504040030702"
sudoku_string_2 = "# Example Sudoku\n" + \
              "*72****6*\n" + \
              "***72*9*4\n" + \
              "*9*1****2\n" + \
              "*******4*\n" + \
              "82*4*71**\n" + \
              "**9*6*8**\n" + \
              "***9**6**\n" + \
              "**3*72*9*\n" + \
              "*6*843*7*"

s1 = Sudoku(sudoku_string_1)
s1.solve()
print(s1.to_oneliner())

s2 = Sudoku(sudoku_string_2)
s2.solve()
print(s2)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dlxsudoku import Sudoku
ImportError: cannot import name Sudoku
```

If I change 'Sudoku' to 'sudoku' on line 1, i.e.

```
from dlxsudoku import sudoku
```

The error changes to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\sandbox.py", line 15, in <module>
    s1 = Sudoku(sudoku_string_1)
NameError: name 'Sudoku' is not defined
```

and if I try to fix this by changing line 15 to

```
s1 = sudoku(sudoku_string_1)
```

the error again changes to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\sandbox.py", line 15, in <module>
    s1 = sudoku(sudoku_string_1)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I'm using python version 2.7.5 and I installed the dlxsudoku package using pip command:

```
pip install dlxsudoku
```

as mentioned on the site. I downloaded the dlxsudoku-0.10.1.tar.gz file on which the command was executed.

How do I fix the error and get the package to work? and/or can you suggest any better sudoku solving libraries for python?

Comment: According to your second error, `sudoku` seems to be a sub-package of `dlxsudoku`. Have you tried `from dlxsudoku.sudoku import Sudoku`?

Comment: I had'nt tried that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
from dlxsudoku.sudoku import Sudoku
```

Answer (score 1):

As creator of the package, I have now updated the package (`0.10.2`) so that you can import both like

```
from dlxsudoku import Sudoku
```

and

```
from dlxsudoku.sudoku import Sudoku
```

I intended to make the first one standard, but I seems I had forgotten make the necessary imports in the `0.10.1`...